# Android How to pass data from Activity to Fragment once successful volley request?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to pass data from an activity to a fragment via `BroadcastReceiver`. But I cant get the data in the fragment,cause the `onReceive()` there not fire up.

**In my AppConfig:**

```
public static final String CREATE_POST = "created_post";
```

**In activity A implement all this stuff :**

```
 StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.MYURL, new Response.Listener<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(AppConfig.CREATE_POST);
    intent.putExtra("myId",myId);
    intent.putExtra("userId",userId);
    intent.putExtra("username",username);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

**In the fragment with should be receive the data I already implement this :**

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcasterReceiver;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//..other code here

    broadcasterReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          if(intent.getAction().equals(AppConfig.CREATE_POST)){
             Log.d("Broadcast","get called")
             //HERE I get the intent here
          }
       }

 }


//I already register the boardcast in onResume() and onPause()
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //register the broadcaster
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(broadcasterReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(AppConfig.CREATE_POST));
    }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
   //unregister the broadcaster
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(broadcasterReceiver);
    }
```

What I still missing out? In order to make this work.

Comment: `why my BroadcastReceiver not fire up?` short answer, because you didn't fire it!

Comment: where should I fire it ya??

Comment: when you want that !

Comment: `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);` is it this one in Activity that I want to send the data??

Comment: You have called `sendBroadcast()` on what point ? You need to edit your question with proper code .

Comment: I sendBroadcast when successfully call the API using volley

Comment: Have you added it in `AndroidManifest.XML`

Comment: nope..I never add in manifest @Heisen-Berg how should I do this??

Comment: @Heisen-Berg there is no need for registration in manifest when doing it runtime. @OP You should add the minimal code for flow to us to make sure the `BroadcastReceiver` is in register state when you fire it .

Comment: @ADM I update my question..please take a look

Comment: Log the fragment state Make sure the `Receiver` is register not unregistered. Whereas this is not really a `BroadcastReceiver` uses . You can achieve this by simply a callback interface .

Comment: Is there a specific need for you to send data via a `BroadcastReceiver`? Because it can be done with the help of `interface` as well.

Comment: @camelCaseCoder how can I use the Interface method? Can show me how to do??

Comment: Okay hold on, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @ken first the receiver should be registered then only you can send the data to the receiver.. !! ]

Comment: @SantanuSur I think I already register in onResume() .Or am I missing out something??

Comment: @camelCaseCoder **Android why my BroadcastReceiver not fire up?** cannot have an answer like how to use callback interface. !!

Comment: @camelCaseCoder I change my question..wait a moment

Comment: in `onResume` of what are your registering the receiver? @ken

Comment: @camelCaseCoder bro I already change the question? is it ok now??

Comment: @SantanuSur onResume() of the Fragment that should be receiving the broadcast

Comment: and when was the fragment transaction @ken before sending the broadcast?

Comment: would you mind posting the whole activity code ? @ken

Comment: @SantanuSur I cant post the whole activity code..is too alot of code..Can you provide me the example how should it be done?

Comment: 1st there should be fragment transaction or the fragment should be created first.. **only then you can send the broadcast**

Comment: @SantanuSur is it receive the broadcast??cause Fragment is receive,Activity is send the broadcast.

Comment: yes the receiver should be registered first.. and after that you can send the broadcast.. **send is later.. receive is first to be precise**

Comment: You are registering the "postBroadcasterReceiver" instead of "broadcasterReceiver" in onResume and onPause(), please make sure that which broadcast is you fire and register, both are same or not.

Comment: @ken I've posted my answer

Comment: I think you are un-registering the receiver before sending the broadcast. Put logs on onResume() and  onPause() and see what is the last call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, create an `interface` anywhere in your package. For eg -

```
public interface SyncDataListener {
    void refreshDashboard(String myId, String username, String userId);
}
```

Then in your **Activity**, create a global declaration and setter/resetter methods like -

```
private SyncDataListener syncDataListener;

public void setSyncDataListener(SyncDataListener syncDataListener) {
    this.syncDataListener = syncDataListener;
}

public void resetSyncDataListener(){
    syncDataListener = null;
}
```

Next in your **Fragment** implement the above `interface` and override the method like -

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment implements SyncDataListener {  
    @Override
    public void refreshDashboard(String myId, String username, String userId) {
        //Your code that deals with the data received from activity
    }
}
```

Also in the **Fragment**'s `onAttach(Context context)` method call the setter method created in the activity like -

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setSyncDataListener(this);
}
```

Also make sure you reset the listener instance when your **Fragment** gets destroyed like -

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).resetSyncDataListener();
}
```

Now whenever you need to send data from `Activity` to `Fragment` you can call -

```
if (syncDataListener != null) {
    syncDataListener.refreshDashboard(myId, username, userId);
}
```

Comment: bro the `data` in `syncDataListener` how can it be the data in `myId,username,userId` in activity A part in my question??

Comment: how can I put in the `myId,username,userId` inside the `data`?

Comment: You can add any number of parameters to the `refreshDashboard` method. Modify the method as `void refreshDashboard(String myId, String username, String userId);`

Comment: Updated my answer with your params

Comment: this `Interface` method is just like the `Protocol` in Ios..am I right?/

Comment: An `interface` is a Java concept that is used to define an abstract type with methods without definitions

Comment: the mainActivity is it refer to the activity that contain the fragment??

Comment: Yeah the `Activity` you're trying to send the data from

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166226/discussion-between-camelcasecoder-and-ken).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code , this is work in my side :

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcasterReceiver;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//..other code here

    broadcasterReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          if(intent.getAction().equals(AppConfig.CREATE_POST)){
             Log.d("Broadcast","get called")
             //HERE I get the intent here
          }
       }

 }


//I already register the boardcast in onResume() and onPause()
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //register the broadcaster
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(broadcasterReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(AppConfig.CREATE_POST));
    }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
   //unregister the broadcaster
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(broadcasterReceiver);
    }
```

use this code to register the broadcast